# Custom post type clean shortlink

Tags: permalinks

In a multisite installation I want to change the shortlink for custom post types from this `http://example.com/site/?p=5` to this `http://example.com/site/5`

I saw that if I set the permalinks settings to `/%post_id%/` it's working fine.

Is this an official acceptable way or just a hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is correct. You can choose custom permalink the way you want. But it is limited to these official [tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) only.

And `%post_id%` is one of those tags so you can use it.

Just a note here you need to end the custom structure with post ID or name as codex says

> Make sure to end your structure with either `%post_id%` or `%postname%`
>   (e.g. `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`) so that each permalink
>   points to an individual post.